# Error : vb.net sqlite create database with password

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, passwords

i face problem when i try create sqlite database with password.

When I create database without password it is work very good but if i try to set password it give me error message "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.117.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=433d9874d0bb98c5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.".

[image: Error Message]

My Code :
[image: My Code]

[image: My Installed packages]

**My Code Is :**

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim DB_Path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\DB\database.sqlite"

    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            If File.Exists(DB_Path) = False Then
                ' create db folder if not exist
                If Not (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\DB\")) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath & "\DB\")
                End If

                ' Create a new SQLite connection
                Using conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DB\database.sqlite" & ";Version=3;")

                    'set db password
                    conn.SetPassword("ashraf123") ' the error here
                    'change db conn string
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & DB_Path & ";Password=ashraf123;Version=3;"
                    'open conn
                    Await conn.OpenAsync
                    ' do somthing

                End Using
            Else

                Using conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & DB_Path & ";Password=ashraf123;Version=3;")
                    Await conn.OpenAsync
                    ' do somthing

                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried that change platform from any cpu to x86.
I tried that change platform from any cpu to x64.
I tried that Copy system.data.sqlite.dll and all other .dll files to startup app folder.
I tried uninstall all packages and reinstalled them again.
i tried creat new project and do all mentioned steps.

Comment: `System.Data.SQLite` requires the [SEE](https://sqlite.org/com/see.html) extension to work with encrypted databases.

Answer (score 0):

install this package **SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher**
and use the password in connection string like this :

> Data Source=" & DB_Path & ";Password=ashraf123

Comment: i tried your answer it give me same error message : "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.117.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=433d9874d0bb98c5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."